# What are the composite functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

f : $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
[image]

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1n,&x\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }x=\frac{1}n\text{ in lowest terms}\\
\sqrt{2},&x=0\ 
\end{cases}$$

g(x) is the inverse of f(x)

determine
whether (g ◦ f) (R) and (f ◦ g) (R) exist, and, if they do, determine what they are.

I think the composite functions does not exists because f(x) and g(x) are inverse of each other.  So Range of g is not the subset of domain of f, and range of f is not the subset of domain of g.

Can someone help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: how are f and g inverses of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(f(x)) = \frac{1}{q}$ x in rational $x = \frac{p}{q}$ in lowest terms otherwise $\sqrt{2}$.

$f(g(x))= 0$ if $x = 0$ otherwise $\frac{1}{n}$ and $x=\frac{1}{n}$ in lowest terms